# Updating Knockout viewModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout-2.0

I'm attempting to update a knockout view model, but each time I try to push to an observable array it gives me an error that AuditViewModel is undefined.

```
function (data, update) {
        if (update == false) {
            var AuditViewModel = {
                auditEvents: ko.observableArray(data.requirements)
            };

            ko.applyBindings(AuditViewModel);
        } else {
            AuditViewModel.auditEvents.push(data.requirements);
        }
    }
```

On the page load this function always runs with update == false, and that originally populates the view model. When I later call with update ==true then it fails. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the line `var AuditViewModel = { ... }` is only executed if `update == false`.  Because AuditViewModel is a local variable, if you later call the function when `update == true`, AuditViewModel will be undefined.

You will need to store the view model elsewhere, ie: `window.AuditViewModel = { ... }`.

Example:

```
function (data, update) {
    if (update == false) {
        window.AuditViewModel = {
            auditEvents: ko.observableArray(data.requirements)
        };

        ko.applyBindings(window.AuditViewModel);
    } else {
        window.AuditViewModel.auditEvents.push(data.requirements);
    }
}
```